# Bluetooth does not have execute permissions, cannot start

Tags: permissions, bluetooth

My bluetooth headphones refused to work for a minute as bluetooth wouldn't pick them up, so I disabled it through the GUI and tried to reactivate it, I was able to flip the on/off but under it the window still said "Bluetooth is disabled"
So I tried to execute it from the terminal with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start"
```

but it returned:

```
* Starting bluetooth
start-stop-daemon: unable to start /usr/sbin/bluetoothd (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

I went into terminal and did `sudo nautilus`, went into the 'usr/sbin' and changed the permissions of "bluetoothd" to allow executing and change the group from root to my group.

Hope this helps anyone else with similar problems!